# How to invoke the right method in django inherited model

Tags: python, django, oop

I have a model classes B and C which implements a method f and inherits from model class A.
I want to invoke the function f on all A instances (B and C).
Why do

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    a.f()
```

Doesn't work as expected?

Comment: What was the expected behavior, and what did you observe?

Comment: I expected that for each instance their f method (B.f for B, C.f for C). What happened that it tried to invoke the A.f method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the default django manager doesn't manage polymorphism. So when you do

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    …
```

All your `a` objects are of type A, and no type B or C.

You need to use the [django-model-utils](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/overview) application, and it's `select_subclasses` tool:

```
for a in A.objects.select_subclasses():
    # type(a) returns the correct subclass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in A.objects.all():    
    hasattr(a,'f') and callable(a.f) and a.f()
```

So first check if a has 'f' attribute, then if its callable and finally call it.

Comment: Even if the class A implements an f method I want to f method of the inherited class to be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If your model shares same data (ie you only want custom methods) you can use the proxy trick describe here: http://anthony-tresontani.github.com/Python/2012/09/11/django-polymorphism/